# how to find family of curve with a maxima and minima

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How to find the family of curve in 2D such that it has minima at two points suppose x=a and x=c, and maxima at x=b where a< b < c.
I can find a single curve because y’ =0 at maxima and minima. So $y’ = 0$ at x=a, b, c.         so,
$y' = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c) $
By integrating it we can find a single curve.
But how can we find a family of curve?

Comment: Add a constant? Multiply by a constant?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You were almost write. In fact, since $$y' = k(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$$ is a solution (with $k \neq 0$). we need $k>0$ in order to reach a maximimum at $x=a$.

Now, expanding the product and integrating with respect to $x$  , you would arrive,after minor rearrangements, to $$y=k_1 x \left(3 x^3-4(a+b+c) x^2 +6 (a b+a c + b c)x-12 a b c\right)+k_2$$ still with $k_1>0$.